# Running web application from bin\debug folder

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to configure IIS to look for DLLs in the `bin\Debug` directory (as opposed to the bin directory). I tried updating my web.config, with the following line:

```
 <runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <probing privatePath="bin\Debug" />
</assemblyBinding>
```

However, it still doesn't see that directory. Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: Related post - [Use "debug" and "release" folder with ASP.NET web application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18575180/465053)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's only for secondary assemblies. Jeff Atwood has [blogged](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/11/multiple-bin-folders-in-aspnet.html) about it. You cannot entirely replace the `bin` folder. It just allows you to define an additional probing folder.